# How can I get an item with the same name as the nearest player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Something along the lines of:

```
/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {display:{Name:@p}}
```

but this obviously is not working. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible.  As far as I know, all values in data tags need to be literals.

Answer (score 1):

I spent I few hours researching this one! An answer by JooshNF:

> This is not possible unless you know all the players who will press
>   it. If so, you would need a setup like this;
>
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ALia.png
>
> Command 1: /execute @e[type=WitherSkull] ~ ~ ~ /testfor
>   @p[name=(player's name),r=5]
>
> Command 2: /setblock x y z command_block 0 replace {Command:"/give @p
>   (item) 1 0 {display:{Name"(player's name)"}}}
>
> To summon witherskull: /summon WitherSkull ~ ~ ~
>   {direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0]}
>   So, this is basically impossible.

Click [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/2319650-name-an-item-based-on-player-name) for original thread.

If I helped you, please mark this up, and, if you found it useful, please mark as answer.